# Trying to loop through Json

Tags: jquery, json

```
$('#myClick2').change(function () {
   if (this.checked) {
     $.getJSON('message_center_getMessageLists.asp', {}, function (json) {

             $.each(json.items, function (i, item) {
              alert(item.rank.distID);
              alert(item.rank.name);
              alert(item.rank.description);
             });
         })
         .error(function () {
           alert("There was an error while trying to make this request;  If it persists please contact support"); 
   });
  }
});
```

I cannot seem to get the above to work, I have to be missing something.

Below is the Json I am trying to loop through

```
{
    "rank": [
        {
            "distID": "1",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "description": "My Rank"
        },
        {
            "distID": "2",
            "name": "Jane Dow",
            "description": "My Rank"
        },
        {
            "distID": "3",
            "name": "Robin Doe",
            "description": "My Rank"
        },
        {
            "distID": "4",
            "name": "Ryan Doe",
            "description": "My Rank"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen. What errors do you get.

Comment: Do you have an error message? what doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Do you get any output at all? Do you have any error messages in the [Javascript console](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html)?

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors that I saw.

Comment: items doesn't existing in the json?

Comment: @3nigma thanks for editing, wasn't sure how to make the Json look pretty.

Comment: @JamesWilson http://jsonlint.com/ its a good resource to validate your json...

Comment: @3nigma I used that site.  Didn't even think to use it to format the code to print it here.  Will do that from now on.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you might want:

> $.each(json.rank, function(i, item)

?

Comment: Yeah, I had just tested that right after I posted and it works perfectly now.  Was trying to find a way to delete the question, but since you gave the correct answer it is yours.

Answer (score 2):

If that's your JSON response, you need this:

```
$.each(json.rank, function (i, item) {
    alert(item.distID);
    alert(item.name);
    alert(item.description);
});
```

This is because your JSON is an object with one property named `rank` and that property contains an array of objects that are what you want to iterate over.  So you pass `json.rank` to `$.each()` and you will get each object in the array as `item`.

Adding some line breaks so you can see it better, this is your JSON response:

```
{
    "rank": [
        {"distID":"1","name":"John Doe","description":"My Rank"},
        {"distID":"2","name":"Jane Dow","description":"My Rank"},
        {"distID":"3","name":"Robin Doe","description":"My Rank"},
        {"distID":"4","name":"Ryan Doe","description":"My Rank"}
    ]
}
```

So if that was set equal to your success argument `json`, you can see how the array would be `json.rank`.  And, then you'd access each items properties inside the `.each()` loop with `item.distId`, `item.description`, etc...

Answer (score -1):

well, item.rank doesnt make any sense. The value of rank is an array of JSON objects. What you actually want is to loop over the elements of rank. This syntax will be iffy but

```
$.each(json.items.rank (i, item) {
  alert(distId);
});
```

Comment: There is no data element called `items` anywhere.  This isn't correct.